# Change Sprite frame at run time - Cocos2d v 3 or 3.2.1 - setDisplayFrame not found

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In Cocos2d 2.x I used below code to change Sprite frame at run time.

```
    //#define SPRITE_CACHE ([CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache])
    [carSprite setDisplayFrame:[SPRITE_CACHE spriteFrameByName:@"redCar.png"]];
```

How can I achieve this in Cocos2d v3.x and above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh..

Its just simply API name change. setDisplayFrame = setSpriteFrame !!!

```
    #define SPRITE_CACHE ([CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache])
    [carSprite setSpriteFrame:[SPRITE_CACHE spriteFrameByName:@"redCar.png"]];
```

Comment: or simply: carSprite.spriteFrame = [SPRITE_CACHE spriteFrameByName:@"redCar.png"]